# How do I get LibreOffice to run on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: libreoffice

Recently I upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 and I have had three problems, screen flickering in some of my games, Banshee freezing, and LibreOffice which wont even load (I know it's a cheap shot to include so many problems in one post, but if you have a solution it is much appreciated). Unfortunately no handy dandy error messages showed up so I debugged it from the terminal and got the following:

```
edmund@edmund-VGC-LT25E:~$ libreoffice --debug

(soffice:2329): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(soffice:2329): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(soffice:2329): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(soffice:2329): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
page 2: illegal page type or format
PANIC: Invalid argument
/home/edmund/.libreoffice/3/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages.db: pgin failed for page 2
PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
page 2: illegal page type or format
PANIC: Invalid argument
/home/edmund/.libreoffice/3/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages.db: pgin failed for page 2
PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
page 2: illegal page type or format
PANIC: Invalid argument
/home/edmund/.libreoffice/3/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages.db: pgin failed for page 2
PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
page 2: illegal page type or format
PANIC: Invalid argument
/home/edmund/.libreoffice/3/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages.db: pgin failed for page 2
PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
page 2: illegal page type or format
PANIC: Invalid argument
/home/edmund/.libreoffice/3/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages.db: pgin failed for page 2
PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
page 2: illegal page type or format
PANIC: Invalid argument
/home/edmund/.libreoffice/3/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages.db: pgin failed for page 2
PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
page 2: illegal page type or format
PANIC: Invalid argument
/home/edmund/.libreoffice/3/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages.db: pgin failed for page 2
PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
page 2: illegal page type or format
PANIC: Invalid argument
/home/edmund/.libreoffice/3/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages.db: pgin failed for page 2
PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
page 2: illegal page type or format
PANIC: Invalid argument
/home/edmund/.libreoffice/3/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages.db: pgin failed for page 2
PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
page 2: illegal page type or format
PANIC: Invalid argument
/home/edmund/.libreoffice/3/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages.db: pgin failed for page 2
PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
page 2: illegal page type or format
PANIC: Invalid argument
/home/edmund/.libreoffice/3/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages.db: pgin failed for page 2
PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
page 2: illegal page type or format
PANIC: Invalid argument
/home/edmund/.libreoffice/3/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages.db: pgin failed for page 2
PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
page 2: illegal page type or format
PANIC: Invalid argument
/home/edmund/.libreoffice/3/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages.db: pgin failed for page 2
PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
page 2: illegal page type or format
PANIC: Invalid argument
/home/edmund/.libreoffice/3/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages.db: pgin failed for page 2
PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
page 2: illegal page type or format
PANIC: Invalid argument
/home/edmund/.libreoffice/3/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages.db: pgin failed for page 2
PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
page 2: illegal page type or format
PANIC: Invalid argument
/home/edmund/.libreoffice/3/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages.db: pgin failed for page 2
PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
page 2: illegal page type or format
PANIC: Invalid argument
/home/edmund/.libreoffice/3/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages.db: pgin failed for page 2
PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
page 2: illegal page type or format
PANIC: Invalid argument
/home/edmund/.libreoffice/3/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages.db: pgin failed for page 2
PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
page 2: illegal page type or format
PANIC: Invalid argument
/home/edmund/.libreoffice/3/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages.db: pgin failed for page 2
PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
page 2: illegal page type or format
PANIC: Invalid argument
/home/edmund/.libreoffice/3/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages.db: pgin failed for page 2
PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
page 2: illegal page type or format
PANIC: Invalid argument
/home/edmund/.libreoffice/3/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages.db: pgin failed for page 2
PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
page 2: illegal page type or format
PANIC: Invalid argument
/home/edmund/.libreoffice/3/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages.db: pgin failed for page 2
PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
page 2: illegal page type or format
PANIC: Invalid argument
/home/edmund/.libreoffice/3/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages.db: pgin failed for page 2
PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery
```

LibreOffice did end up running from the terminal if that is any help.

I used a rather unorthodox method of backup when I upgraded to 11.10, which entailed copying the home folder to windows and the merging it back into Ubuntu.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall several times with no success.

Comment: Try `mv ~/.libreoffice/3/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages.db{,.bak}`

Comment: mv: cannot stat `/home/edmund/.libreoffice/3/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages.db': No such file or directory.

Comment: Can you be more specific please on what that is supposed to do?

Comment: mv: missing destination file operand after /home/edmund/.libreoffice/3/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages.db

Comment: I think what @amphetamachine is thinking is that the file l.o. is complaining about is corrupt, so he told you to move it, so you could run thhe program without it (but still have it backed up if you need it back).  I would go one step further and tell you to back up the whole folder (`mv ~/.libreoffice{,-backup}`).

Comment: Thank you, but now that I have debugged, it appears to work: I will update if it stops working again.

Answer (score 1):

Reinstalling won't help, as it is pretty clear from the error messages that the problem is in the settings directory, `~/.libreoffice/`. And, of course, uninstalling or reinstalling will *never* touch settings under `~`.

If you want the "equivalent" of a "clean" reinstall, rename `~/.libreoffice` to something else. But beware that this is just a dirty fix, you may actually want to keep some of your settings.

(This is what @Kevin suggested, but said using different words.)